# How to upload a Latex file with images referenced in it,into a mysql database

Tags: mathjax, php, mysql

So I have this php/mysql/latex/mathjax quiz generating system.I can create a latex document of questions and upload the file and my system extracts the questions and answers,stores them in a mysql database and generates the quiz on the frontend etc. So now I have a challenge,I need to include some graphs and diagrams in my question banks.I know how to reference an image in a tex file but how can I go about getting the graphs and diagrams as part of the question that gets stored into the mysql database?Is there any way around it? thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What is the question exactly? How to find out which part of the LaTeX code uses which image? Or how to upload image files to your database and use them in your frontend? The first question would be on topic, although it would probably be much easier to manually select and upload image files when you upload the LaTeX file. The second question or any other question related to databases, php, MathJax etc. would not be on-topic and should be asked on a different site.

Comment: Try whether base64-encoding the image and using filecontents helps…

Comment: I have done some extra reading around and it seems there is a way to base64-encode the images into the latex source file.I will try this out and update if i get it right.Thanks guys for your time!